# How to set the maximum date in uidatepicker to december current year in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, datepicker

1.I want to set the maximum year to select as December current year in datepicker, .How to do that , please help
2. In time picker only 30 and 0 mins should be enabled to select . How to do this , am stuck please help

Answer (score 2):

create Date Which u set As maximum date

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:day];
[comps setMonth:month];
[comps setYear:year];
[comps setHour:hour];
[comps setMinute:minute];
[comps setSecond:second];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *YourDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```

To set Maximum date

```
  [_pickerDate setMaximumDate:YourDate]
```

To set Time InterVAl 30 minutes

```
 [_pickerDate setMinuteInterval:30]
```

Comment: [_pickerDate setMinuteInterval:30] worked , thanks!!

Comment: @ShilpaM accept the answer pls if worked.It would help future readers

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. use maximumDate property in UIDatePicker

   max, the values are ignored. Ignored in countdown timer mode
   @property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate *maximumDate; // default is nil
2. you can set desired value in valueChanged event to desirable 30 or 0 mins or use this property

   @property (nonatomic) NSInteger      minuteInterval;    // display minutes wheel with interval. interval must be evenly divided into 60. default is 1. min is 1, max is 30

Comment: Is there a option to remove minute display and show only hours in datepicker?